# Ruby on Rails MVC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, bootstrap-4

I working on an application based on Ruby on Rails with Bootstrap. I am stuck on the backend. I am not clear how to insert some records in Database which is Active record. i have attached screenshot of my database tables and also my code. I hope i get the right answer here.

This is my Controller :

```
class ImportCsvController < ApplicationController
  before_action :require_user
  before_action :require_admin

  def index
  end

  # Import CSV file from Sysinflame
  def import
  end

  def import_csv_datei
    begin
      @import_csvs = FileUploadInfo.new(params[:file])
      if @import_csvs.read_save_csv(params[:file])
        #Import Successful
        user=current_user.user_name
        time = Time.now
        FileUploadInfo.import_file(params[:file],time.to_formatted_s(time),"erfolgreich",user)
        redirect_to :back, notice: "Import Erfolgreich!"
      else
        #return errors
        #format.html {render :index}
        #format.json {render json: {status:"Fehler: ",message: "Dateiformat ist nicht erlaubt!"}}
        redirect_to :back, notice: "Fehler"
      end
    #rescue
      #redirect_to root_path, notice: "Invalid CSV file format."
    end
  end
end
```

now here comes my Model class :

```
class FileUploadInfo < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'csv'
  def initialize(file)
    @file = file
  end

  def read_save_csv(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, :headers => true) do |row|
    file_hash = row.to_hash
    end
    return true
  end

  def import_file(file,time,status,user)

  end

end
```

[image: This is my Table in Database]

[image: This is my user Table]

i am stuck on import_file function and need some advices here. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can just initialize your model and use create method:
You can just initialize your model and use save method:

```
file = FileUploadInfo.new
file.filename = filename
file.importdate = importdate
file.status = status
file.username = username

if file.save
   // File saved succesfully
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. I have found the workaround and below is my modified controller and it works pretty well.

```
  class ImportCsvController < ApplicationController
  before_action :require_user
  before_action :require_admin

  def index
      # get the last 5 import history for dashboard
      @Fileimport = FileUploadInfo.order('updated_at DESC').limit(5)
  end

  # Import CSV file
  def import_csv_datei
    begin
        user=current_user.user_name
        time = Time.now
        status= "OK"
        filepath = params[:file]
        @file = FileUploadInfo.new
        @file.filename = filepath.original_filename
        @file.importdate = time.to_formatted_s(time)
        @file.status = status
        @file.username = user
        if @file.save
            #Import Successful
            #FileUploadInfo.import_file(params[:file],time.to_formatted_s(time),"erfolgreich",user)
            redirect_to :back, notice: "Import Erfolgreich!"
        else
            #return errors
            #format.html {render :index}
            #format.json {render json: {status:"Fehler: ",message: "Dateiformat ist nicht erlaubt!"}}
            redirect_to :back, notice: "Fehler"
        end
    rescue
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "Invalid CSV file format."
    end
  end
end
```